# Creating a Private App to Connect with Amazon SP-API: Developer and Seller Account Clarifications

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I'm currently a developer working for a company that manages product and order processes between brands, clients, and marketplaces. We are looking to expand our services to Amazon using the SP-API and need to create a private app.

However, I'm facing some uncertainty regarding the required accounts. I currently have access to a seller account from one of the brands we work with, but Amazon is asking me to complete the developer profile.

My question is: Can I use my company's information to fill out the developer profile, or should I use the brand's information (which didn't belong to our company) associated with the seller account? Can I use the same app credentials for another seller account ?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Register as a public developer for Amazon SP-API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826125/register-as-a-public-developer-for-amazon-sp-api)